# VirtualHost with wildcard VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: apache2, xampp, wildcard, virtualhost, directoryindex

I'm trying to create a fallback for my virtual hosts. My configuration looks like this:

```sh
# Fetch all pre-defined hosts

Include "conf/extra/vhosts/*.conf"

# Fallback

NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "C:/LocalServer/usr">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/LocalServer/usr/%-1/projects/%-2+/public/"
</VirtualHost>
```

The objective here is the following: If I try to access `http://test.lab/`, I want it to automatically pick up the following directory: `C:/LocalServer/usr/lab/projects/test/public/`.

Now, I have created the folders, and an empty index file (`index.php`). Nonetheless, Apache keeps showing me an empty Directory Index ("Index of").

No quite sure what to do now. Have tried a few things, none of which seem to work.

Any ideas?

## Update - 1 June

I am now using this code, based on the first answer (well, the only one):

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.lab
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/LocalServer/%2/%1/public"
    <Directory "C:/LocalServer/%2/%1/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I now get an **Access forbidden** error from Apache. One would surely, normally, receive this error when the directory does not exist? `C:/LocalServer/lab/test/public` does exist, and an empty `index.php` resides in the `public` directory.

The error in the general error log: `[client 127.0.0.1:49342] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/LocalServer/lab/test/public/`

If I remove the `<Directory/>` group, nothing changes. I still get the error. (Can I even use `%n` in that group?)

### Quick Note:

The reason it wasn't working before was due to the fact that I had other Virtual Hosts being imported, by means of the `Include "conf/extra/vhosts/*.conf"` instruction. Commenting it out (and thus making the Labs rule the only one) initiated the **Access forbidden** error.

Also note that I am no longer using the `usr` folder - each Lab is now in the `lab` folder, under `LocalServer`.

## Update 2

It seems that the `<Directory/>` block does not allow for variables to be inserted, like `VirtualDocumentRoot` does.

## Update 3 - Solution Found

It is now working - would not have been able to do it without the help. Here's the final code:

```sh
<VirtualHost lab:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.lab
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/LocalServer/%2/%1/public"
    <Directory "C:/LocalServer/lab/*/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Update 4 (April 2015)

**New Directive, for those interested (using latest Apache 2.4):**

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/home/%-2+/public_html"
    <Directory "D:/home/*/public_html">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This, with the combination of [Acrylic DNS Proxy](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome), makes magic.

## Update 5 (December 2016)

I'm now using a [Macro approach](https://blog.rockett.pw/posts/use-macros-to-define-your-virtual-hosts-in-apache).

```sh
# Directory Macro - Default Directory configuration on a per-vhost basis

<Macro Directory $dir>
    <Directory "z:/var/www/$dir/public_html">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</Macro>

# LocalSub Macro - For specific *.*.local subs that require their own root

<Macro LocalSub $sub $domain>
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
        ServerName $sub.$domain.local
        DocumentRoot “z:/var/www/$domain/$sub/public_html”
        Use Directory $domain/$sub
    </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

Use LocalSub blog rockettpw

# Main virtual host

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.local *.*.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot “z:/var/www/%-2/public_html”
    Use Directory *
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Has nobody had this problem before? It seems that the rules are working, but pointing to the wrong place, and I can't figure out where that place is.

Comment: What does your host file look like? And still using the same? Is it possible to have the documents on another drive? (Non SSD)

Comment: @SuperSpy - Naturally, I have an entry for each domain (though, I'm no longer using *.lab). That said, I'm currently trying to get [Acrylic DNS Proxy working](http://superuser.com/questions/896335/acrylic-dns-proxy-not-resolving). I would think so, but I always keep my server on the same drive as my site-data.

Comment: Why did you stop using lab? And what would the vhost file look like without lab?

Comment: I switched to `.local`. Setup is the same - just swapped the `lab` with `local`.

Comment: I notice for me the setup only works if I change `lab` into an asterisk  `<VirtualHost lab:80>` any clue why that is the case?

Comment: Your NameVirtualHost may be set to `*:80`, which means the `VirtualHost` directive must be set to match. I have updated my question to show you what I am currently using.

Comment: Update 4 was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MikeRockett Thanks for sharing, helped a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use them :) You forgot about switching off canonical names - unfortunately I don't know why there must be ServerAlias in my configuration - it just won't work without it - code below is tested and working

```
<Directory "C:/LocalServer/*/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require local
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Apache will form URLs using the hostname supplied by the client
    UseCanonicalName Off

    # available aliases to use
    ServerAlias *.lab *.lab2

    # where to put them
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/LocalServer/%2/%1/public/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I did try something quite similar to that, albeit with a few more lines of the usual stuff. Will try your attempt exactly as you have it. Hope it works! :)

Comment: try to define <Directory> as I did it - it must work - "Require local" is optional

Comment: Thanks! I picked up the Directory problem - and initially just used `lab/`. But, yours is better. Wouldn't have been able to fix this without you - many thanks!

Comment: I think "Require all granted" is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are obviously using windows for development, but (presumably) deploying to linux for production, have you thought about using a virtual machine for development?

I've written a guide for setting up here: http://otaqui.com/blog/1652/setting-up-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-for-web-development-with-multiple-sites-using-mod_vhost_alias-and-virtualdocumentroot/ but in essence:

- Share a directory (e.g. C:\VirtualWWW) from the HOST to the GUEST
- Mount that share as /var/www in the GUEST, with www-data as the owner
- Setup vhost_alias and VirtualDocumentRoot to map subdirectories in C:\VirtualWWW to virtual host subdomains, i.e. C:\VirtualWWW\project1 is mapped to http://project1.vhost/

Setting up new projects is then as simple as creating a new directory on your host, and the virtual machine guest uses that.  If you are deploying to linux, you might save yourself all sorts of headaches (filename case-sensitivity being only one).