# Apache: virtualhost on each sub-domain to corresponding directory

Tags: apache, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName $variable.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/$variable
</VirtualHost>
```

for example if I go to `foo.example.com` it must show me `/var/www/foo` directory content

What is the good apache syntax for that?

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714293/sharing-configuration-between-several-vhosts/18722685#18722685 for mass-visrtualhosting panel of solutions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have `$variable` like that in servername and map it to the document root, but you can use mod_rewrite and a wildcard.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*::\1
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The `subdomain.example.com` can just be any subdomain that isn't `www.example.com`. For any request that doesn't start with "www", the subdomain is captured as a group (2nd condition), then the next line makes sure the request isn't already being routed into the subdomain's name, and the rule routes it.

So for the request:

```
http://foo.example.com/bar/x.html
```

it gets routed to:

```
/foo/bar/x.html
```

Comment: You can use a wildcard with a virtual document root. See Update 4 of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747013/virtualhost-with-wildcard-virtualdocumentroot

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use with my freelancer work:

Under httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
UseCanonicalName Off
<VirtualHost *:${AP_PORT}>
 DocumentRoot ${US_ROOTF_WWW}/_client
 ServerName client
 ServerAlias client
 <Directory "${HOME}\www\_client">
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:${AP_PORT}>
 VirtualDocumentRoot "${US_ROOTF_WWW}/_client/%1"
 ServerName subdomains.client
 ServerAlias *.client
 <Directory "${HOME}\www\_client\*">
   Require all granted
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Then under the windows hosts file place the domain and subdomains that are needed.

```
127.0.0.1 client
127.0.0.1 someone.client
127.0.0.1 someone2.client
```